# For loop works fine outside of function but throws error inside of function

Tags: python, function

I have a for loop that works flawlessly outside of a function and I decided to put it inside a function so I'm not typing it out every time but it keeps throwing an error. The function does is pass a geojson file and an empty list to append.

**For loop (outside of function *works*):**

```
for feature in geojson['features']:
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
        points.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])    
        points.append([None, None])   
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
        for polyg in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            points.extend(polyg[0])
            points.append([None, None])
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString': 
        points.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
        points.append([None, None])
    elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiLineString': 
        for line in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
            points.extend(line)
            points.append([None, None])
    else: pass
```

**Function:**

```
import json

geojson = json.load(open("towns.geojson"))

points= []

def coordinate_extract(geojson_file, empty_list):
    for feature in geojson_file['features']:
        if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Polygon':
            empty_list.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0])    
            empty_list.append([None, None]) # mark the end of a polygon   
        elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
            for polyg in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
                empty_list.extend(polyg[0])
                empty_list.append([None, None]) #end of polygon
        elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString': 
            empty_list.extend(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
            empty_list.append([None, None])
        elif feature['geometry']['type'] == 'MultiLineString': 
            for line in feature['geometry']['coordinates']:
                empty_list.extend(line)
                empty_list.append([None, None])
        else: pass   
    print(empty_list)

coordinate_extract('geojson', 'points')
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

I don't understand why I'm getting this error on `line 8` inside of the function but not outside. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you passing strings as arguments here: `coordinate_extract('geojson', 'points')`?

Comment: `coordinate_extract('geojson', 'points')` This is using the literal strings `"geojson"` and `"points"` as arguments, _not_ the variables of those names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coordinate_extract('geojson', 'points')
```

You're mistakingly passing in a string, instead of the actual object geojson that contains your json data.

So your for loop is trying to access an index in a string, which works but a string only contains numerical indices.

Just remove the quotations and pass in geojson & the points array as an object and list respectively, not as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use quotations on your variables while calling the function.

It is considering the inputs as a string, where you are expecting variables.

```
coordinate_extract(geojson, points)
```

You sir, definitely need to start from basics

Comment: Haha yes! I hardly use functions in my programming but I want to start using more thanks for the easy solution.

Comment: Kudos to you. You can close this question then. Have a great day..!